# Strange Behavior in Language usage in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, tamil

I had been used `FontFamily="Bamini Plain"` in the text box which was allowing me to type the tamil language text during runtime. But when I capture                 `txtPlaceAcquire.Text` in the code behind which returns english text. Why this strange behaviour? how can I get my original language value?

```
<TextBox Text="" Name="txtPlaceAcquire"  Width="210" Margin="10,0" FontFamily="Bamini Plain" />  <!-- Tamil language font setup -->

var textCapuredVal =  txtPlaceAcquire.Text;  // It was given english value
```

Comment: Because Bamini font is not a unicode font.

Comment: what is the difference between unicode and plain font ?

Comment: Please suggest some links if you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a Tamil and had dealt with so much of Tamil encodings I think I should enlighten you on this issue. Bamini is doesn't belong to any encodings such as TAB, TAM, TSCII or the universal standard Unicode. Bamini font is having Tamil scripts on top of English script.

So I would suggest you to start using Unicode font. There are amble of Tamil fonts available online. Even windows comes with a default Unicode Tamil font `latha.ttf`.

To type in Tamil use softwares like [e-kalappai](http://www.thamizha.com/project/ekalappai) or [NHM writer](http://software.nhm.in/products/writer). Or you can use online converters such as [Google IME](http://www.google.lk/inputtools/windows/).

I'd suggest you to give up Bamini and go ahead with Unicode fonts. If you insist on usinb Bamini then you should do code level encoding changes between Bamini and Unicode. [Check out this class written in Java](https://github.com/mayooresan/Android-Tamil/blob/master/src/com/mayuonline/tamildemo/TamilFontUtil.java) and see how it is done. You gonna have to do soemthing like this.

Comment: Hi. I'm very much delighted to see your answer also very much happier to see about your tamil enthusiasm. I'd like to go with Bamini with conversion logic written by you. Hence could you confirm will it covers all the letters translation ?

Comment: @RameshMuthiah yes it covers full conversion.

Comment: Then that would be nice. Thanks i can straight a way use this conversion

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with no problem, and it returns unicode text for me, I put it in a answer, as I cannot add images in the comment. See below image.

[image]

Comment: http://www.ufonts.com/fonts/bamini-plain.html try this original version and let me know